# css issue with responsive design in shopify

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, shopify

I am trying to get responsive footer in shopify. The thing that bothers me is this:

```
 <ul class="footer-costume_ul site-footer__linklist{% unless section.settings.footer_newsletter_enable %} site-footer__linklist--center{% endunless %}">
            {% for link in linklists[section.settings.footer_linklist].links %}
              <li class="site-footer__linklist-item footer_pipe">
                <a class="footer_a" href="{{ link.url }}"{% if link.active %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}>{{ link.title }}</a>
              </li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
```

The links in footer are out generated and I am piping them.

```
.footer-costume_ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
list-style: none;

}


.footer_a {
     margin-left: 1rem;
}

.footer_pipe + .footer_pipe::before {
  padding-rigt:10px;
  content: "|";
}
```

When resolution is mobile it does not disply ok as words are not breaked in new line.

[image]

How to deal with this that per li it will auto break in new line words when this is needed.

I manage to get this: 
[image]

But the thing is that I do not know how to pipe this corretly. thank you.

tnx
miha

Comment: What would you like for the result? "Način plačila" and "Dostava" to be in separate lines? Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: No, I need like this (when there is not enough width). Exp "Vracila '\n'  Reklamacije | Nacin '\n' plaiča | Dostava | Kontakt". So when there is not enought width i need to brake it new line, so that whole "ul" stay in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question, you have a few options here. I will assume that you are using "mobile-first" approach. Simply set `li` to `block` (the element will "live" on its own line) or set its width to `flex-basis: 100%`.

```
.site-footer__linklist-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  /* flex-basis: 100%; // this is alternative */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
   /* please note that 480px is arbitrary. You decide on the breaking point. */

  .site-footer__linklist-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto
    /* flex-basis: auto; // you can use "auto" or "initial" */
  }
}
```

There's probably a dozen other ways to achieve this, but the point is the same. Target the element for widths that are "mobile" and make each `li` take the whole line for itself.

Flex-wrap will break the line only if there's not enough room for 2 elements to live together. It will not automatically break the line (by default). Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe I did not express my self correctly. What I need to achive is that the linklist is one the same line (link1 link1 | link2 link2 | link3 link3), what bothers me is this. When there is enouht width due to mobile view, i need to brak words like "test \n test | test2 \n test2 | test3 \n test3". This must be done auto based on width (I can not add "\n")